# printing to text file line by line with toString

Tags: java, file, io, newline

I can print line by line using toString to the console, but how come it doesn't do the same when I put it in a textfile?

```
public class NewClass
{

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return ("John " + "\n" + "jumps " + "\n" + "fences");
    }
}


import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;


public class Sandbox
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {
        NewClass object = new NewClass();            

        FileWriter file = new FileWriter("output.txt");
        PrintWriter output = new PrintWriter(file);
        output.println(object.toString());    
        output.close(); 
        System.out.println(object.toString());

    }
}
```

**CONSOLE OUTPUT:**

John

jumps

fences

**output.txt**

John jumps fences

Comment: What Operating System are you using and which text editor?

Comment: @user1615805 Notepad expects CRLF (`\r\n`)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you are on Windows, instead of `\n` use `\r\n` (carriage return + line feed).

Or better yet, use [`System.getProperty("line.separator")`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/sysprop.html) to *obtain the sequence used by operating system to separate lines in text files*.

Comment: Hmm... specification for [`PrintWriter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html): *These methods use the platform's own notion of line separator rather than the newline character.*

Comment: @oldrinb: Yes, but OP is printing a *single* line using `PrintWriter`. The others are hard-coded in `NewClass#toString()`, using `\n`.

Answer (score -1):

Windows files need \r\n (carriage return and new line). Unix files just need \n. To make it compatible with both, you can use FileOutputStream:

```
try {
    FileOutputStream file = new FileOutputStream(new File("output.txt"));
    byte[] b = object.toString().getBytes();
    file.write(b);
} catch (Exception e) {
    //take care of IO Exception or do nothing here
}
```

You may have to surround this with a try-catch statement as shown.